# Validating user authentication from another machine

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, authentication, windows-authentication

I'm trying to implement SSO on a windows domain.  I already have a service that allows a user to log in via username and password, and this works great.  What I'm looking for is a when a user logs into their machine via a domain (controller), what do I need to send the other server to allow it to verify that the user is authenticated against the domain.  So what I'm asking is, is there a way to get an authentication hash/key from the user, that can be sent to another server, and that server use it as credentials against the domain?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: so there are two windows domains. You want the user to login your service on a machine in domain A, then the user does not need to login again on a machine in domain B? By matching the windows login ID?

Comment: no single domain, but it shouldn't matter one or multiple, the authentication should validate with its corresponding domain.  Assume one for now.  User Logs into Machine A.  Machine A connects to Server B and sends some form of credentials to Server B.  Server B connects and verifies credentials on Domain C.  Program D doesn't have access to users password on machine A though.